# How to create an AlertDialog before an sms text is sent?

Tags: android, sms

I would like to know if it is possible to create an AlertDialog before a text message is sent from the default messaging app. I have looked at other people's questions on intercepting outgoing sms messages, however, those only seem to show how to read the message and not actually prevent it from being sent. I also do not want to create my own messaging app from scratch, so please do not suggest that. Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: you can't do that. There is no broadcast for outgoing SMS, and no way to abort a send.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a new `AlertDialog` object like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Now lets say the SMS you want to send is triggered by the click of a button. Lets call it sendSMS. Inside the onClick method set the parameters of the `AlertDialog` object like this :

```
sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                     builder.setMessage("You are about to send an SMS! are you sure you want to send it?")
                    .setTitle("Warning!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {

                            //*******************************
                            //PUT HERE THE SMS SENDING CODE!!!
                            //*******************************

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            //closes the dialog; nothing interesting happens here
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

This displays an `AlertDialog` with the click of a button, warning the  user that he/she is about to send an SMS. If he/she clicks yes then, the SMS code is triggered. If he/she clicks no nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, I specified that I want to create an AlertDialog based on whether or not an SMS is sent from the *default messaging app.* In other words, I don't have access to the button that actually sends the SMS, so I wouldn't be able to use your example. Still, thanks for your response; your code looks very nice.